# upload image from android SDcard to a php server doesn'twork

Tags: php, android

I'm trying the code of this   [tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

but i'm getting this log erroe :
: Source File not exist :/mnt/sdcard/desert.png
well i entred into : DDMS ,and i drag and droped the image in the /mnt/sdcard
but it doesnt't work either , i added the permissions too .
Please suggest me a solution or an idea to solve this problem.
an thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you drop any file in DDMS at that time DDMS not refreshed as well. So you have to restart your emulator to take effect of file which you drag in sdCard.

Answer (score 1):

Might ou need to refresh emulator,Go to DDMS view and reset adb connection to refresh it.Click on rightmost downward arrow to get reset adb option.

Comment: I refreshed it ,restart emulater ,still the same error, what i shoul a do ?I even push 2 times the picture in the sdcard to make sure that it exists ,but it didn't tell me that the sdcard already contains the picture ,it means it doen't exist there ! :''(